# Perl - Print div by class

Tags: html, css, perl, dom

I need to print a specific `div` with class `productSpecs` from a webpage. Here is my code.

```
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath qw();

my $url="http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-b310e-guru-music-2/p/itmdz9am8xehucbx";
my $content = get($url);
my $t = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$t->parse($content);
my $rank = $t->findvalue('//*[@class="productSpecs"]');
print $rank;
```

But I am not getting the content I want. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspecting the HTML code you are trying to parse, the required `div` node has this declaration:

```
<div class="productSpecs specSection">
```

so your code should be:

```
my $rank = $t->findnodes('//div[@class="productSpecs specSection"]');
```

Comment: I gives the text ... but I need it with HTML...How can I get the HTML inside the div element?

Comment: +1 good catch :-) I followed up on your answer in mine and tried to explain why the only the rendered text appeared but not the full HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Hi user2186465 and welcome to Stack Exchange :-)

When you assign and print the output from`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`'s `findnodes->()` method it seems to default to parsing/rendering the `<div>` node and returning the content as text. Along with that it returns an `XML::XPathEngine::NodeSet` object (which `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` uses) and an array with a reference to an `HTML::Tree` object that has what you want. You need to assign that array element reference to your `$rank` variable or else you'll just get the text:

```
my $rank = $t->findnodes('//div[@class="productSpecs specSection"]')->[0];
```

(**NB:** this appears somewhere in the documentation as an example, but it is not prominent).  Once you have the `HTML::Element` object you can use one of its methods with your print statement to get at the contents.

Without the `->[0]` you get the rendered text and `print $rank` just shows that; but with `->[0]` you get access to the object and its methods so `print $rank->as_HTML` can show the raw HTML content from the node (`->as_XML` works as well). `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` also has a `as_XML_indented` convenience method to make the output easier to read. So:

```
use strict;                                                              
use LWP::Simple;                                                            
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath qw();                                  

my $url="http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-b310e-guru-music-2/p/itmdz9am8xehucbx";
my $content = get($url);                                                        
my $t = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;  
$t->parse($content);   
my $rank = $t->findnodes('//div[@class="productSpecs specSection"]')->[0]; 
print $rank->as_XML_indented ;
```

should do what you want.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Just for comparison I tried this with Mojolicious using the `ojo` tool (great for oneliners) and it seems [`Mojo::DOM`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Dom) returns the HTML by default unless you ask for the text with a `->text()` method. *e.g.* this seems to do what you want:

```
perl -Mojo -E 'g("http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-b310e-guru-music-2/p/itmdz9am8xehucbx")
 ->dom->find("div.productSpecs")->each(sub{say $_})'
```

cheers,